# Use PTZ controls on Axis Camera

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an Axis camera (AXIS M5014 PTZ) and I am using [axis_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/axis_camera) package to get the video stream. The video stream using `axis.py` works perfectly fine.

Now I am trying to use `axis_ptz.py` node to control PTZ parameters of the camera. Firstly, there is barely any documentation on this page explaining how you can actually set the parameters for dynamic configuration. After some research I found that `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure` opens a GUI for you to set parameters on different available variables. Now, only "pan" variable works, and "tilt" doesn't do anything. Are there and examples/tutorials/documentation that can help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196062/use-ptz-controls-on-axis-camera/) by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 281 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `teleop.py` node subscribes to `sensor_msgs/Joy` and publishes `axis_camera/Axis` messages. If you have a joystick, you should be able to control the PTZ using it.

The `axis_ptz.py` node subscribes to the `cmd` topic and receives the published `axis_camera/Axis` in order to control the PTZ unit.

In a nutshell, if you publish `axis_camera/Axis` messages from your node, you should be able to control the PTZ unit. I based myself on the `teleop.py` when I wrote my own node.

As for the dynamic reconfigure, I haven't tried that out.

I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2